# 2D Array seems to change values as c++ class member

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member

I have got a strange behavior when using a double pointer to array in my programm like this:

```
 /* in a.h  
  */
 class A{
   private:
     int _n;
     int _m;
     int _p;
     int _dim;
     int** _t1;
     int** _t2;

   public:
     ~A();
     A();
     A(const A& a);
     A& operator=(const A& a);
     A(int n, int m, std::string filename);
 };

 int readfile(int* p, int* dim, int*** t1, std::string filename);

 /* in a.cpp  
 */
 A::A(int n, int m, std::string filename){
   _n = n;
   _m = m;
   _t1 = NULL;
   _t2 = NULL;

   int ierr;
   ierr = readfile(&_p, &_dim, &_t1, filename);
   // print _t1[i][j] here : no problem

   // fill _t2 from _t1 : PROBLEM!!
   _t2 = new int*[_p];
    // check allocation
    for(int k = 0; k < _p; k++){
       _t2[k] = new int[_dim];
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < _p; k++){
        for(int j = 0; j < _dim; j++){
          _t2[k][j] = 0;
        }
     }

     int In, ie, nv;

     for(int k = 0; k < _p; k++){
          nv = _t1[k][_dim];
          if(nv == dim){
             for(int in = 0; in < nv; in++){
                 In = _t1[k][in];
                 ie = _t2[In][_dim];
                 _t2[In][ie] = k;
                 _t2[In][_dim] += 1;
             }
          }
       }

 }

 int readfile(int* p, int* dim, int*** t1, std::string filename){

   std::ifstream fid;  
   std::string line;
   std::stringstream pline;

   fid.open(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);
   if( !fid.is_open() ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error : Can't open %s ...\n", filename.c_str() );
        exit( -1 );
    }

    getline(fid, line);
    pline.str(line);
    pline >> (*p);

    getline(fid, line);
    pline.str(line);
    pline >> (*dim);

    *t1 = new int*[(*p)];
    // check allocation
    for(int k = 0; k < *p; k++){
       (*t1)[k] = new int[(*dim)];
    }

    int j;
    for(int k = 0; k < *p; k++){
       getline(fid, line);
       pline.str(line);
       j = 0;
       while( pline >> (*t1)[k][j] ){ j += 1};
    }
    fid.close();

    return ( 0 );
 }
```

The fact is: the double pointer '_t1' is being allocated and filled from the function 'readfile(...)'. This is OK since the simple 'print' shows that the values have been properly read from the file.
Now, the array '_t2' is allocated inside the class A constructor; when I start filling _t2 from _t1, it appears that the values in array _t1 have changed, and I don't figure out why! 
After calling the function readfile(...), nothing else is performed on array the _t1, but when I print its value during assignment of _t2, they are no more the same as the first print. I've been thinking the array _t1 has been passed correctly to the function readfile(...) by reference, may I'm missing something! May Someone find something!!!

Comment: array _t1 is allocated within function readfile(__) and _t2 is allocated as _t2 = new int*[_p];                                           for(int k = 0; k < _p; k++){_t2[k] = new int[_dim]; } This is done just after calling function readfile(__) in the class A constructor!

Comment: You're probably facing *pointer aliasing* (t1 and t2 point to the same memory).

Comment: the fact is I did allocate new memory for _t2; but its values have to be filled from those of array _t1.

Comment: You haven't shown your code for copying _t1 into _t2.

Comment: What does `// fill _t2 from _t1` look like?

Comment: See http://wp.me/p3w1Pr-3 (Pw: p2pbad) on why you should (imho) avoid 2d pointer-to-pointer stuff in c++ in general. Write (and ensure functionality to) or download a class that handles the memory stuff and use it. The code will get simpler, cleaner, easier to extend and the debugging will be much easier. You can use a function to transfer your data accoding to what you want to do.

Comment: Been coding in C too long - all those _names scare me into thinking I'm stomping system calls.